# Can't find the issue in this VBA module that pulls data from one .xls file to another

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first time posting here. I've been working on a VBA module which is intended to, at the click of a button, allow the user to select a .xls file and import all data from the top (only) sheet for use in calculations in other sheets. I have two exact copies of this module set to deposit the data into two different worksheets of the same workbook. One of them is working fine; the second, the one I'm having trouble with, only imports rows 1-3, and I have no idea why (I have almost 0 experience with VBA :). Here's the code--please help!

```
Private Sub btn_GetScrapReport_Click()

     '   Local Variables
    Dim wrkBook         As Workbook
    Dim fd              As FileDialog
    Dim strComPath      As String
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant


    Debug.Print "Getting File Name"

     '   Using FileOpen Dialog box get target file
    strComPath = "N:\Users\OEECalc\ScrapReports"
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        .InitialFileName = strComPath
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
         'Add filter to only show excel files.
        .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls", 1
         ' Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
        If .Show = -1 Then
            strFilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
             ' The user pressed Cancel.
            MsgBox "You must select a file to import before proceeding", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "No file Selected, exiting"
            Set fd = Nothing
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

     '   Open The File and Import
    Set wrkBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFilePath, ReadOnly:=True)
    Call Import_WOData(wrkBook)
    wrkBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set fd = Nothing
End Sub

Sub Import_WOData(wrkbookSource As Workbook)

     '   Local Variables


     '   Clear import data range
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ScrapReport").Range("A1:A65536").EntireRow.ClearContents

     '   Assumption is that workbook only contains a single sheet and the data starts ( headers ) in A1
    With wrkbookSource.ActiveSheet
        .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ScrapReport").Range("A1")
    End With

End Sub
```

The other (working) module is identical, with the exception of every instance of "ScrapReport" being replaced with "ReleaseWO"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your issue is that it is not importing all of the data from the sheet, and instead it stops at line three. This could be because cell A4 is blank, and your code assume full and contiguous data.

This block of code says to start at the first cell, continue downwards until the first empty cell, and then copy all of those rows.

```
With wrkbookSource.ActiveSheet
    .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Copy  Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ScrapReport").Range("A1")
End With
```

If the table is complete and contiguous this is fine. If there is a chance that your first column may be empty, you could switch this to

```
wrkbookSource.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ScrapReport").Range("A1")
```

This should select all the used cells in the sheet regardless of contiguity. It has its own downsides -- once a range is considered "used" its almost always considered "used" even if it is now empty -- but maybe that won't matter for you and there are work-arounds if it does.